# masking sign extension using right shift operator >>

Tags: java

I'm currently learning bitwise operator and have encountered the following example in the book "Java the complete reference the ninth edition".

I understand what right shift operator >> does, but I'm not exactly sure how this example actually works (maybe I don't understand how >> works after all). Could someone please kindly explain it to me?

> Sometimes it is not desirable to sign-extend values when you are
>   shifting them to the right. For example, the following program
>   converts a byte value to its hexadecimal string representation. Notice
>   that the shifted value is masked by ANDing it with 0x0f to discard any
>   sign-extended bits so that the value can be used as an index into the
>   array of hexadecimal characters.

```
// Masking sign extension.

class HexByte {

    static public void main(String args[]) {
        char hex[] = {
            '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
            '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
        };
        byte b = (byte) 0xf1;
        System.out.println("b = 0x" + hex[(b >> 4) & 0x0f] + hex[b & 0x0f]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Before starting to explain it would be helpfull to know, if you have knowledge on the binary, decimal and hexadecimal system?  If you know how to convert numbers between these three systems, the explanation is much easier ^^

Comment: @MeinName I do understand the difference between different numbering system. I can do basic conversion between them, with certain amount of time and thinking though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signed left shift by 4 keeps the sign of the original number.

However ((byte)0xf1) >> 4 is -1 which isn't what you want.

You just want the lower 4 bits which is where the `& 0x0f` gives you just the lower 4 bits. This gives you `0xf` which is the top 4 bits or 15.

Comment: Why should (0xf1 >> 4) be -1? Shouldn't it be 15?
Edit: oh because it is a byte ^^

Comment: @MeinName It is. `(0x000000f1 >> 4)` is 15. but `((byte) 0xf1) >> 4)` is `(0xfffffff1 >> 4)` or -1

Comment: @PeterLawrey thank you for the explanation. This bit thing is so confusing. Do you have any good reading recommendation on the topic? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @TonyStark I suggest playing with the operations printing out what each one does in Hexadecimal.  I learnt this stuff long before I had access to the internet so I have no idea which would be good (except using google).

Answer (score 1):

In your example b is set to 0xf1 (11110001). B >> 4  results in this: 11111111.

Because Java is using *arithmetic shift*, after executing a right shift, the leftmost digit will be 1 (unlike *logical shifts* whhich will leave a zero at the end).

To fix this issue you execute 11111111& 0x0f (00001111) which results to 00001111.